# Hard time installing jspm-bower-endpoint

Tags: npm, jspm

I want to be able to install bower packages through jspm and I am running the following commands as explained [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspm-bower-endpoint)

`sudo npm install -g jspm-bower-endpoint && jspm registry create bower jspm-bower-endpoint`

But the terminal gives back the following response[image: Terminal response]

Is there another way to get around this?

Comment: try installing w/o -g flag, i.e. locally `npm install jspm-bower-endpoint`